# Area of Rectangle and circle

Tags: geometry, area

Just a basic question :

The area of a rectangle is length×width because I'm filling the length with width. This makes sense to me but if I do the same approach for a circle then the area becomes $2\pi$$r^\text{2}$. What am I missing here ?

Comment: How is that the "same approach"? For the circle it seems you're multiplying the entire circumference by half the width. Is that what you did with the rectangle?

Comment: what i'm trying to do for the rectangle area is thinking the line which is width (let's say 2 cm) equals to 2cm2 and then adding all those 2cm2's until the number of lenght. so with the same thinking r as the width and the lenght is 2piR.

Comment: So the question is, _how_ is $r$ the "width" of a circle and _how_ is $2\pi r$ the "length"? A better analogy might be getting the area of a triangle from its base and its altitude.

Answer (score 1):

This image might help to understand the circle's area compared with a rectangle:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't quite work because the circumference is not the same for smaller radii. What you really want to do is to "sum" over all different circumferences $2\pi R$ for $R \leq r$. This is done properly via the integral, i.e. take $2\pi R$ and integrate it over the interval $[0,r]$. Then you get the right result.

Further reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri%27s_principle